# Rails Omniauth Gem redirect url mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am new to Rails and I am stuck with this issue for sometime now. We are using Omniauth Gem in our Rails application for authentication. I have a sessions controller which specifies the redirect_url. The authentication is happening successfully but the url is not what we are expecting it to be.

Response URL: 
`https://mycompany****/oauth/authorize?client_id=259fb843dc20d1b7&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Frailswebserver%2Fauth%2Fprovider%2Fcallback&response_type=code&state=fe144f693105a30223cab09c68eb95ecdf58a0e248a679e8`

The redirect_uri is still pointing to /auth/provider/callback while we expect it to append what is mentioned in the sessions controller. I have no clue how the client_id is picked in this response url as the one I mentioned in my yml file is different.

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController 
  def new 
   redirect_to "/auth/#{OAUTH_SETTINGS["auth_provider"]}" 
  end

  def create 
    omniauth_data = env["omniauth.auth"] 
    username = omniauth_data['info']['username'] session[:user_id] = username 
    redirect_path = root_path + "/docs/index.html" redirect_path = cookies[:return_url] 
    if !cookies[:return_url].blank? 
      cookies[:return_url] = nil 
      redirect_to redirect_path
```

`oauth.yml 
development: 
auth_provider: 'provider' 
oauth_root_url: 'mycompany******.com' 
oauth_client_id: '259***************************8a76b3629b843dc20d1b7' oauth_secret: 'e9c697***************************b9c3bfa82f5f893ca1' docs_root_url: 'railswebserver';`

Comment: Please post the `sessions_controller.rb` and the yml file contents for review.

Comment: sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    redirect_to "/auth/#{OAUTH_SETTINGS["auth_provider"]}"
  end

  def create
    omniauth_data = env["omniauth.auth"]
    username = omniauth_data['info']['username']
    session[:user_id] = username
    redirect_path = root_path + "/docs/index.html"
    redirect_path = cookies[:return_url] if !cookies[:return_url].blank?
    cookies[:return_url] = nil
    redirect_to redirect_path

Comment: oauth.yml

development:
  auth_provider: 'provider'
  oauth_root_url: 'https://mycompany******.com'
  oauth_client_id: '259***************************8a76b3629b843dc20d1b7'
  oauth_secret: 'e9c697***************************b9c3bfa82f5f893ca1'
  docs_root_url: 'https://railswebserver'

Comment: Please add the code to the question and format it.

Comment: done, can you pls help